# Read configuration settings from azure cloud service with .NET C#

Tags: c#, settings, azure-cloud-services

I am searching for a way to read settings from a deployed windows azure cloud service with C#. Is there any Azure SDK available to easily load this values?

Screenshot from Azure Portal to show which settings i want to read:

[image]

[EDIT1]

I missed to add that I tried to load the settings from an external application and not from the service it self.

Comment: In light of the edit, I've removed my answer. I'm not sure about how you can do that - sorry.

Comment: Technically possible as Bruce answered, but why would you want to do that? seems like an incorrect approach to share configuration..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you could leverage [Microsoft Azure Management Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.windowsazure.management.libraries) to retrieve the configuration settings, you could follow the steps below:

- [Create a new self-signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-certs-create#create-a-new-self-signed-certificate)
- Export the cert to a .cer file and upload it to your azure subscription, for more details, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-api-management-certs)

I created a console application and reference the **Microsoft Azure Management Libraries**, here is the core code:

```html
private static X509Certificate2 GetStoreCertificate(string thumbprint)
{
  List<StoreLocation> locations = new List<StoreLocation>
  { 
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser, 
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine
  };

  foreach (var location in locations)
  {
    X509Store store = new X509Store("My", location);
    try
    {
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
      X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
      if (certificates.Count == 1)
      {
        return certificates[0];
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      store.Close();
    }
  }
  throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
    "A Certificate with Thumbprint '{0}' could not be located.",
    thumbprint));
}
```

```html
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CertificateCloudCredentials credential = new CertificateCloudCredentials("{subscriptionId}", GetStoreCertificate("{thumbprint}"));
    using (var computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential))
    {
        var result = computeClient.HostedServices.GetDetailed("{your-cloudservice-name}");
        var productionDeployment=result.Deployments.Where(d => d.DeploymentSlot == DeploymentSlot.Production).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You could retrieve the configuration settings from `productionDeployment.Configuration` as follows:

[image]