# Azure Cloud configuration in c#

Tags: azure, cloud

I am trying to read Azure Configuration values and I also followed the answer provided in

[Read configuration settings from azure cloud service with .NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488854/read-configuration-settings-from-azure-cloud-service-with-net-c-sharp)

I want to know from where I can get the following parameter values:

1. subscriptionId
2. thumbprint
3. StoreLocation.CurrentUser
4. StoreLocation.LocalMachine
5. X509Store store = new X509Store("My", location) -- what i need to write at the place of "My"

Answer (score 0):

> -- what i need to write at the place of "My"

You also need to use **My**. For more information please refer to [What are the Windows system certificate stores?](https://superuser.com/questions/217719/what-are-the-windows-system-certificate-stores/222724#222724)

> Each of the three stores contain a number of folders which certificates go into
>
> - **Personal** (can be known as **My** when using scripts to add certs)
> - Trusted Root Certification Authority (can be known as Root)
> - Enterprise Trust
> - Intermediate Certification Authority
> - Active Directory User Object
> - Trusted Publishers
> - Untrusted Certificates
> - Third Party Root Certification Authorities
> - Trusted People

We could get the **subscriptionId** from Azure portal, details please refer to this [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mschray/2016/03/18/getting-your-azure-subscription-guid-new-portal/).

About **thumbprint** please refer to How to: [Retrieve the Thumbprint of a Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-retrieve-the-thumbprint-of-a-certificate)

**StoreLocation.CurrentUser** and **StoreLocation.LocalMachine** is [StoreLocation Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storelocation?view=netframework-4.7.2)